# Why my DateTime format changed on Bamboo build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, bamboo

I have a `User` class that `has_many` `Jobs`. I map jobs with the following code, the start_at and end_at are datetime:

```
def ranges
  user.jobs.map { |u| [u.start_at, u.end_at] }
end
```

I have a spec that compares two arrays:

```
my_array = [[start1, end1], [start2, end2]]
expect(ranges).to eq my_array
```

The test data are also datetime created from factory girl e.g.

```
create(:jobs, start_at:DateTime.parse('2017-03-26 00:00:00'), end_at: DateTime.parse('2017-03-27 00:00:00'))
```

Everything works fine, expect when Bamboo runs my spec, I get following error:

```
expect 
[[2017-12-31 00:00:00.000000000 +0000, 2017-12-31 10:10:00.000000000 +0000], [2017-12-30 00:00:00.000000000 +0000, 2017-12-31 00:10:00.000000000 +0000], [2017-11-26 00:00:00.000000000 +0000, 2017-11-26 10:10:00.000000000 +0000], [2017-03-24 00:00:00.000000000 +0000, 2017-03-24 10:10:00.000000000 +0000], [2017-03-25 00:00:00.000000000 +0000, 2017-03-25 10:10:00.000000000 +0000], [2017-03-26 00:00:00.000000000 +0000, 2017-03-26 10:10:00.000000000 +0000]]
```

to match

```
[[Sun, 26 Mar 2017 00:00:00 UTC +00:00, Sun, 26 Mar 2017 10:10:00 UTC +00:00], [Sat, 25 Mar 2017 00:00:00 UTC +00:00, Sat, 25 Mar 2017 10:10:00 UTC +00:00], [Fri, 24 Mar 2017 00:00:00 UTC +00:00, Fri, 24 Mar 2017 10:10:00 UTC +00:00], [Sun, 26 Nov 2017 00:00:00 UTC +00:00, Sun, 26 Nov 2017 10:10:00 UTC +00:00], [Sat, 30 Dec 2017 00:00:00 UTC +00:00, Sun, 31 Dec 2017 00:10:00 UTC +00:00], [Sun, 31 Dec 2017 00:00:00 UTC +00:00, Sun, 31 Dec 2017 10:10:00 UTC +00:00]]
```

dose this mean I need to format all my datetime object by`iso8601` all the time? what could cause this on `Bamboo`

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't your format. The problem is that the array elements are not in the same order. The dates in your `expect` array begin with the 2017-12-31 dates, while those in your `match` array begin with the 2017-03-26 dates.

RSpec's `eq` method returns true only if each element of the first array is identical to the element at the same index of the second array. But the `match_array` method returns true so long as the two arrays have the same elements, regardless of order.

Change your expectation line to:

```
expect(ranges).to match_array(my_array)
```

And you should be good to go.